# Scraping with selenium 4

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

This is the HTML code I am trying to scrape:

```
<div class="vbseo_liked">
<a href="http://www.jamiiforums.com/member.php?u=8355" rel="nofollow">Nyaralego</a>
,
<a href="http://www.jamiiforums.com/member.php?u=8870" rel="nofollow">Sikonge</a>
,
<a href="http://www.jamiiforums.com/member.php?u=8979" rel="nofollow">Ab-Titchaz</a>
and
<a onclick="return vbseoui.others_click(this)" href="http://www.jamiiforums.com/kenyan-news/225589-kenyan-and-tanzanian-surburbs.html#">11 others</a>
like this.
</div>
```

This is my code so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


path_to_chromedriver = '/Users/myMac/Desktop/chromedriver' # change path as needed
#browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver)
browser= webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.set_window_size(1120, 550)
#browser.get("http://www.jamiiforums.com/login.php?do=logout&logouthash=1427579705-9d07da3339a5f07bb3a4c9d1001b75dc0431a138")
browser.get("http://www.jamiiforums.com/kenyan-news/225589-kenyan-and-tanzanian-surburbs.html")
username = browser.find_element_by_id("navbar_username")
password = browser.find_element_by_name("vb_login_password_hint")

username.send_keys("")
password.send_keys("")

browser.find_element_by_class_name("loginbutton").click()
link = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="vbseo_liked"]/a[contains(@onclick, "return vbseoui.others_click(this)")]')
link.click()

print 'succes!!'
browser.close()
```

I want to be able to click the link:

```
<a onclick="return vbseoui.others_click(this)" href="http://www.jamiiforums.com/kenyan-news/225589-kenyan-and-tanzanian-surburbs.html#">11 others</a>
```

and then print out the results on the screen after the link has been clicked.

Comment: So, what exactly doesn't work? Can you click on the link? What happens after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a *redirect* happening after logging in. You need to wait for redirect to happen before getting the page source. Here is what worked for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.set_window_size(1120, 550)
browser.get("http://www.jamiiforums.com/kenyan-news/225589-kenyan-and-tanzanian-surburbs.html")

username = browser.find_element_by_id("navbar_username")
password = browser.find_element_by_name("vb_login_password_hint")

username.send_keys("username")
password.send_keys("password")

browser.find_element_by_class_name("loginbutton").click()

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//h2[contains(., "Redirecting")]')))
wait.until(EC.title_contains('Kenyan & Tanzanian'))

print(browser.page_source)

print 'success!!'
browser.close()
```

Comment: I keep getting this error. 
Message: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with xpath '//div[@class=\"vbseo_liked\"]/a[contains(@onclick, \"return vbseoui.others_click(this)\")]'

when i added this code. 
link = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="vbseo_liked"]/a[contains(@onclick, "return vbseoui.others_click(this)")]')
link.click()

Can you please help with that. This is my first time using selenium and xpath. Sorry if it appears pretty basic. I tried getting by class, but it also doesn't work.

Comment: @user3078335 could you please elaborate it into a separate question? Throw me the link to it here in comments too. Thanks.

Comment: I just did.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29354106/screen-scraping-with-selenium-8

Thanks again for your help.