# Screen scraping with selenium 8

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.set_window_size(1120, 550)
browser.get("http://www.jamiiforums.com/kenyan-news/225589-kenyan-and-tanzanian-surburbs.html")

username = browser.find_element_by_id("navbar_username")
password = browser.find_element_by_name("vb_login_password_hint")

username.send_keys("user")
password.send_keys("password")

browser.find_element_by_class_name("loginbutton").click()

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//h2[contains(., "Redirecting")]')))
wait.until(EC.title_contains('Kenyan & Tanzanian'))


link = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="vbseo_liked"]/a[contains(@onclick, "return vbseoui.others_click(this)")]')
link.click()
browser.save_screenshot('screenie.png')
print 'success!!'
browser.close()
```

For this HTML code:

```
<div class="vbseo_liked">
<a href="http://www.jamiiforums.com/member.php?u=8355" rel="nofollow">Nyaralego</a>
,
<a href="http://www.jamiiforums.com/member.php?u=8870" rel="nofollow">Sikonge</a>
,
<a href="http://www.jamiiforums.com/member.php?u=8979" rel="nofollow">Ab-Titchaz</a>
and
<a onclick="return vbseoui.others_click(this)" href="http://www.jamiiforums.com/kenyan-news/225589-kenyan-and-tanzanian-surburbs.html#">11 others</a>
like this.
</div>
```

I want to be able to click on this link:

```
 <a onclick="return vbseoui.others_click(this)" href="http://www.jamiiforums.com/kenyan-news/225589-kenyan-and-tanzanian-surburbs.html#">11 others</a>
```

And then take a screenshot of the page after it has been clicked. This error I keep getting though when i run the code.

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with class name 'vbseo_liked'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *wait for the list of posts to load* before making a click:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get("http://www.jamiiforums.com/kenyan-news/225589-kenyan-and-tanzanian-surburbs.html")

username = browser.find_element_by_id("navbar_username")
password = browser.find_element_by_name("vb_login_password_hint")

username.send_keys("username")
password.send_keys("password")

browser.find_element_by_class_name("loginbutton").click()

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//h2[contains(., "Redirecting")]')))
wait.until(EC.title_contains('Kenyan & Tanzanian'))
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'postlist')))

link = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="vbseo_liked"]/a[contains(@onclick, "return vbseoui.others_click(this)")]')
link.click()

browser.save_screenshot('screenie.png')
print 'success!!'
browser.close()
```

Note that the generated screenshot would be very large (about 39 MB on disk).

Comment: thanks again for your answer. I keep getting a time out error though.
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException:

could it be because it never gets to that page?

Comment: @user3078335 hm interesting, it works for me though. Could you replace `10` with `30` for example? (it really takes time for the `11 others` page to load)

Comment: @user3078335 hm, okay, on which line does it fail? Thanks.

Comment: File "sele.py", line 19, in <module>
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//h2[contains(., "Redirecting")]')))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 75, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: @user3078335 have you provided the correct username and password? :)

Comment: lol.. i figured that was the issue after i posted that error. It's running now. Thanks alot!